# How can we use series representation in limits?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, taylor-expansion

How can we use series representation in limits?

1) We can write $\sin x$ as $$\sin x=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^ix^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!}.$$

How can we write this?

For any given $\epsilon >0$ if we can find $N \geq 0$  such that $$\left|\sum\limits_{i=0}^N \frac{(-1)^ix^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!}- \sin x\right| < \epsilon$$ than the equality $$\sin x=\lim\limits_{N \to \infty}\sum\limits_{i=0}^N\frac{(-1)^ix^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^ix^{2i+1}}{(2i+1)!}$$ will hold.

I am assuming we found this.

2) For $x\ne 0$ (we can show this in same manner) $$\frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^ix^{2(i-1)}}{(2i+1)!}$$ will hold.

3) Here, Our question is $$\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}.$$Using above series represenation we can write it as $$\lim\limits_{x\to0} \frac{\sin x-x}{x^3}=\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(\lim\limits_{N \to \infty}\sum\limits_{i=1}^N\frac{(-1)^ix^{2(i-1)}}{(2i+1)!}\right). $$**My question:** How can we continue from here? If we can write $\lim\limits_{x\to0}\lim\limits_{N \to \infty}$ for $\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\lim\limits_{x \to 0}$, how can we do that?

I want to give an counter-example for last part that limits not always commutative: $$\lim\limits_{x\to0}\left(\lim\limits_{y \to 0}\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right)=\lim\limits_{x\to0}1=1$$ and $$\lim\limits_{y\to0}\left(\lim\limits_{x \to 0}\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right)=\lim\limits_{x\to0}-1=-1.$$

***I want to note that*** my question is not just for this particular example.

Comment: Your  series for $\sin\; x$ is wrong: missing $(-1)^i$

Comment: Oh, thanks, I will edit now.

Comment: EXCELLENT question which shows you have the right attitude about mathematics. Whenever "we do something," QUESTION why we can do it. Perfect example - if you change the order of taking limits, WHY is that permitted (especially when you know it is NOT OK to do in general). You must be able to state specifically what it is, in your particular problem, that allows you to do something. In your example, it is not just the convergence of the series that allows you to change the order, but the UNIFORM convergence.

Comment: after correcting for the ${\left( { - 1} \right)^{\,i} }$ what is now the connection between 1) and 2) ? cannot understand what is the problem

Comment: First part is motivation for what I did and where I stuck. The question is after "My question" and it is about continuation the rest of calculation in right way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has to do with special properties of *power series*; in particular the function defined by a power series is *continuous* on the interval where it converges:

Suppose $\sum a_nx^n$ converges for $|x|<R$. Fix $r\in(0,R)$, and say $r<\rho<R$. The series converges for $x=\rho$, and hence the terms are bounded for $x=\rho$; this shows that the series converges uniformly on $[-r,r]$, and hence the sum is continuous on $[-r,r]$.

Comment: Yes, of course, if it is continuous, we can just calculate series for $x=0$. Thanks.

Comment: @studentforever Right. I purposely left the punchline to you....

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this is with $O$ notation.  If $f(x) = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i$, converging for $|x| < R$ where $R > 0$, then 
$f(x) = a_0 + a_1 x + \ldots + a_n x^n + O(x^{n+1})$ as $x \to 0$.  So for example, 
$$\sin(x) = x - \dfrac{x^3}{6} + O(x^4)$$
which implies
$$ \dfrac{\sin(x) - x}{x^3} = \dfrac{-x^3/6 + O(x^4)}{x^3} = -\dfrac{1}{6} + O(x) \to -\dfrac{1}{6} \ \text{as $x \to 0$}$$

Comment: This answer's seen as for calculation. But it wasn't the point what I didn't understand. Am I missing something in this answer?